# Request not working for Python AWS Lambda

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, python-requests

on a AWS Lambda function, I have a simple HTTP Request

```
import requests
def lambda_handler(event, context):
     request_headers = {
                      'X-API-KEY': 'somekey',
                      'Content-Type':content,
                      'Host':'somehost',
                    }
     resp = requests.get(some_url_here, headers=request_headers)
     api_response = resp.json()
```

If I set the request  `requests.get(some_url_here, headers=request_headers, verify=False)` I got no issues with the code and it works perfectly, but when I removed it it yields

```
Error encountered: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='x.xxx.xxx.xx', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url:some_url_here (Caused by SSLError(SSLCertVerificationError(1, '[SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: unable to get local issuer certificate (_ssl.c:1124)')))
```

how to fix this issue?

Comment: Is the server cert a self-signed one?

Comment: to be honest I'm not sure about that. Sorry, they just game me an API endpoint that was setup also in AWS.

Comment: The error says that the server certificate could not be verified. So you either need to install the server certificate locally to make the verification work or keep using `verify=False`

Comment: I cant use the verify=False as our security team don't agree with that. Can I install certificate on lambda or on the server itself? Sorry I am not familiar with this. Thank you for the patience

Comment: On lambda the only choice you have is to ask the API team to use a proper certificate that can be verified with the usual certificate chain.